# How can I use an access token with gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud

I have an access token `ya29...0God` and I know that this token has the following permissions `compute.instances.setMetadata`.

I know I can use it to edit the metadata like so:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[PROJECT]/zones/[ZONE]/instances/[INSTANCE-NAME]/setMetadata' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS-TOKEN]' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "fingerprint": "[INSTANCE-METADATA-FINGERPRINT]",
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "ssh-keys",
        "value": "ubuntu:ssh-rsa [SSH-PUBLIC-KEY] ubuntu"
      }
    ]
  }'
```

but I would like to use `gcloud` instead:

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata [INSTANCE] --metadata-from-file ssh-keys=meta.txt
```

Is is possible to configure `gcloud` with an access token ?

Comment: `gcloud` [`--access-token-file`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--access-token-file)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `--access-token-file` flag.

Use this flag to authenticate gcloud with an access token. The credentials of the active account (if it exists) will be ignored. The file should only contain an access token with no other information.

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata [INSTANCE] \ 
       --metadata-from-file ssh-keys=meta.txt \ 
       --access-token-file token.txt
```

Note that this won't work if the token is expired.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--access-token-file

Comment: Please edit your answer with more details including an example using CLI commands. There are side effects such as the token expiring. What procedure should you follow to directly use an access token? As written your post should be a comment on the question.